# How can I use a java .jar file from any directory without typing out the full path?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, java, environment-variables

I'm on Windows 8.1 and I'd like to be able to just type "program" (like regular programs I've put in my PATH environment variable) to launch program.jar as a command line program - including the ability to pass parameters to it. How can I do this?

Comment: Write a batch file and put that in your path.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder containing batch files like the following, and add the folder to the PATH.

`ffmpeg.bat`:

```
@echo off
"C:\Users\user1\Documents\app\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" %*
```

Thanks to DavidPostill for the idea years ago, which seemed like a better option than adding individual program folders to the PATH.